# node js how can I see if the query executes successfully with pg?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

It is possible in pg that I can see if this query can return true or false that I know If the query executed successfully or not :

```
const TrueOrFalse = await db.query('INSERT INTO users (email,password) VALUES ($1, $2);', [email, password]);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "successfully"? If there's an error, you get an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from the documentation:

```
try {
  const res = await client.query(text, values)
  console.log(res.rows[0])
  // { name: 'brianc', email: 'brian.m.carlson@gmail.com' }
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err.stack)
}
```

So yes, it succeeded if it didn't throw an exception.